# Sign in activity keeps spawning after first run

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I am building a sign-in activity (Firebase, Google sign in) that only starts on the application's first run. Problem is that activity persists on spawning even after the authentication process is complete.

I am combining Realtime Database for storing user data into the database when a new user gets registered.

I've run a debugger through the authentication process, which returned no errors or unexpected behavior. I can also confirm that Realtime Database gets queried as expected.

Application is written in the combination of Java and Kotlin.

This is how I call the `SignInActivity` inside `MainActivity` on application's first run (Java)

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Check if this is application's first run
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("first", false).apply();
    }
    }
```

and this is a Kotlin function that commences the authentication process

```
private fun authenticateWithGoogle(account: GoogleSignInAccount?) {
    if (account != null) {
        val credential: AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener{
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        databaseReference.child(account.id!!)
                        val userModel: UserModel? = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel::class.java)
                        if (userModel == null) {
                            databaseReference.child(account.id!!).setValue(UserModel(account.id, account.displayName, account.email))
                            startActivity(Intent(this@SignInActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
                        }
                        startActivity(Intent(this@SignInActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Upon the initial transition from `MainActivity` to `SignInActivity`, the authentication process begins on button press. Function `authenticateWithGoogle` gets called as expected and the database is queried for information whether a user exists or not. If the user exists, just transition back to `MainActivity`, if not, store their data to the database and then transition to `MainActivity`.

At this point, shared preference for storing the state of the first run in `MainActivity` should be set to false, but apparently, it's not, hence why `SignInActivity` gets called again.

Any sort of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: can you confirm if your onResume() gets called in both cases?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that `onResume()` gets called in both cases. Could there be a problem in the way I'm setting a shared preference?

Comment: if you just want to determine if this is the first run of the app. Then just first check the current value of the preference which by default will be true `getBoolean(key, default value)` , if it's true then mark it false, otherwise just keep user on mainActivity itself.

Comment: Yeah, I did just that... Answered my question. Thank you so much for your time and effort, I appreciate it very much!

Comment: I mean keep the "first run logic" on `onCreate()` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem differently, as suggested by [shubham-vashisht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5609146/shubham-vashisht).

So, here's how I did it:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Check if it's application's first run
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstrun", false);
        if (!state) {
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstrun", true);
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
        }
    }
```